# Distinguish between 1000 and 10000 in Select LEFT for groupings

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, select, case

I currently have a Select LEFT that is grabbing the 1st Left digit of an ID field.  This has been working fine so long as our ID number have been 4 digits (0 to 9999)  however we are now introducing 5 digit numbers in the 10,000 range and the current Select LEFT can not tell the difference between 1,000 and 10,000.  The purpose of selecting the first digit (s) is to group the numbers by the thousands (1000, 2000, 3000, . . . , 100000).  What is happening is that the 10000 are now being grouped into the 1000 group instead of a new 10000 group being created.  See code below.

```
SELECT
LEFT(table.IDField,1) as PolicyGroup,
CASE LEFT(table.IDField,1)
   WHEN '1' THEN '1000 Group' 
   WHEN '2' THEN '2000 Group' 
   WHEN '3' THEN '3000 Group' 
   WHEN '4' THEN '4000 Group' 
   WHEN '5' THEN '5000 Group' 
   WHEN '6' THEN '6000 Group' 
   WHEN '7' THEN '7000 Group' 
   WHEN '8' THEN '8000 Group' 
   WHEN '9' THEN '9000 Group' 
   WHEN '10' THEN '10000 Group' 
END as PolicyExplanation,
cpsys_Datacurrent.IntegrationId as PolicyNumber2
```

The ID field is not being padded with anything in front of the number so 4 digits is only 4 digits and 5 is only 5, but I need be able to group by the thousand into and including a 10,000 group.

Comment: You'll probably also have problems with sorting since you've presumably been doing an alphabetic ordering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use arithmetics?

If your database does integer division:

```
IDField / 1000 * 1000 as PolicyExplanation
```

If it doesn't:

```
floor(IDField / 1000) * 1000 as PolicyExplanation
```

If `IDField` is a string, then, depending on your database, explicit conversion might be needed:

```
floor(cast(IDField as int) / 1000) * 1000 as PolicyExplanation
```

Comment: I can't seem to get cast to work on my ID field.  Here is how I wrote it up based on your suggestion, but I get an error with the cast function  (error at bottom of this comment).

Select
floor(cast(cpsys_Datacurrent.IntegrationId as int) / 1000) as PolicyGroup,
CASE floor(cast(cpsys_Datacurrent.IntegrationId as int) / 1000) 
WHEN '1' THEN 'Human Resources' 
WHEN '2' THEN 'General Services/Marketing' 
.
.
WHEN '9' THEN 'Operations' 
WHEN '10' THEN 'Cybersecurity' 
END as PolicyExplanation,

Error - DataSource: Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value to data type int.

Comment: @rjohns68: then it means that some of the values in `IDField` contains something else than just digits. You can use `try_cast()` instead of `cast()` to work around this.

Answer (score 0):

An expression like this would deal with the single-digit problem as well as left pad with a leading zero for sorting purposes:

```
right('0' + cast(cast(IDField as int) / 1000 as varchar(2)) + '000 Group', 11)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Shawn.  I went with GMBs approach as it fit my need better I think.  But I do appreciate your help with your suggestion.